# Check Kerberos access against keytab file

Tags: kerberos

If you have a keytab for a service, can you check locally with Kerberos command line tools if you can get a valid service ticket without having to actually deploy the service, just by having the service's keytab?

e.g.

```
kinit
check_against --verbose httpservice.keytab HTTP/host.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
weberjn@EXAMPLE.COM not allowed for HTTP/host.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Or is there some open source code that does this?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific way you show in your example? No, because neither tickets nor keytabs contain this sort of "user X allowed for service Y" information at all.

A ticket may carry raw facts such as the username or group memberships (the PAC), but they're not verified against a keytab; they're merely *decrypted* using the keytab (it is literally an "encryption key table") but any actual authorization checks would be done by the service's own code/logic. So the only use of a keytab would be to see the raw contents of the PAC from within a ticket, but not to get a pass/fail.

(I don't know any generic tools for decrypting a PAC – there are probably some among the "Active Directory red team" tools.)

In rare cases where authorization checks are done by the KDC before issuing a ticket, the keytab is again useless because the KDC just wouldn't issue the ticket at all if authorization checks had failed – it would not issue a deliberately invalid ticket. So if this were the situation, it would be enough to just request the ticket and see if you get one at all. (I doubt this is the situation, however.)

(MIT Krb5 has the `kvno` command to request a ticket, but there are other ways.)

So as far as "validity" goes, the only check you can do is whether the keytab is able to decrypt the ticket at all (i.e. whether the key in the keytab is in sync with the key at the KDC). For this you don't need the *specific* service, but the easiest way is actually to have the Kerberos library perform the whole authentication procedure *as if* you were the service. In other words, write a minimal Kerberos service that just talks GSSAPI authentication to itself (as both client and server). This is fortunately just a few lines in `python-gssapi`:

```python
keytab = "foo.keytab"

spn = gssapi.Name("HTTP@foo.example.com", gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)

server_creds = gssapi.Credentials(usage="accept", name=spn,
                                  store={"keytab": keytab})

server_ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(usage="accept", creds=server_creds)

client_ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(usage="initiate", name=spn)

# Client: Get the token that would be sent in "Authorization: Negotiate"
c2s_token = client_ctx.step(None)

# Server: Consume the token (verify it against the keytab)
# Throws an exception if the keytab is out of sync with the KDC
s2c_token = server_ctx.step(c2s_token)

# Server: Read out the client principal name from the ticket
if server_ctx.complete:
    print("Authenticated as", server_ctx.initiator_name)
```

This is basically what mod_auth_gssapi (or the legacy mod_auth_kerb) will do to verify a ticket. Again, note that it does not perform any *authorization* checks – all that Kerberos does is say "ticket belongs to user X", while the actual access checks must be done by the program itself.

Comment: E.g. ap24-mod_auth_kerb2 has no more input for its access check than the keytab and the ticket that comes in the Authorization: Negotiate header. So I think the check it does should be possible locally, too.

Comment: What access checks does mod_auth_kerb do? I've used it in the past and I don't recall it having _any_ authorization checks whatsoever, other than "the ticket overall is good" (i.e. decryptable using the keytab).

Comment: Yes, it just checks if the user ticket can access an httpd location, but that's good enough. And this is the check I want locally.

Comment: That doesn't actually check whether the user is "allowed" for anything. All it checks is whether the ticket is not fake, and if you just got the ticket from the KDC, you don't really need to check that.

Comment: But that is how you are supposed to protect an Apache Directory 
with Kerberos: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos

Comment: Sure, but none of it limits access to some specific users like your original example showed. The KDC will issue tickets to any user that exists in the realm database, without regard as to which user wants which service, and the webserver with `Require valid-user` will accept tickets from anyone in the Kerberos realm. Therefore, as long as you can *get* a ticket from the KDC, that ticket is already valid and checking it against the keytab is moot. Any user-level restrictions would be done via Apache config (e.g. "Require user foo@BAR"), or via webapp code, not via Kerberos config.